# Spring boot: Add request parameter in interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to add a parameter when a request is made:

Currently, I'm adding headers using interceptors. However, I'm running against how to add a parameter to the current request:

```
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(
    HttpRequest request,
    byte[] body,
    ClientHttpRequestExecution execution
    ) throws IOException {

        //Adding headers
        request
            .getHeaders()
            .set(
                HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                this.jwtService.getBearer()
            );

        //HOW TO ADD REQUEST PARAMETER HERE???

        return execution.execute(request, body);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot add request parameters to a request. You might be able to construct a completely new `HttpRequest` using the factory. But you would also need to create a new `byte[]` for the body (as that would already contain what needs to be written).

Comment: @Jordi how did you solve your problem?